# How much does video broadcasting on youtube benefit you academic life?

Tags: journals, teaching, audio-video-recording

Recently, I was working on implementing a new optimization approach to publish a paper. Additionally, I've also implemented the other famous existed methods in the area in order to demonstrate the efficacy of my approach.
It is worthwhile to note, I had a lot of difficulty in implementing the existed method as their `Matlab` code was not publicly available anywhere.
So, I thought it is useful to create a series of videos (4-5 video/ 15-20 min each) so that, other researcher can learn how to implement these famous methods in `Matlab`.
Thus, I need a good reason to do so. In other words, what is the outcome for me.
- Would they cite my youtube channel in their paper?
- Does it help my academic reputation?
- Does it help to get a better scholarship for Ph.D. program?
P.S.> I should note that, I have 3 published work in high-rank journals of my field. But if this idea (video broadcasting) doesn't have any significant outcome, I would stick to write another paper and save my time.

Comment: Personally, I would probably prefer a written document over a video for that purpose.

Comment: Personally I learn more from videos than books, But if writing a doc benefits me more, I'll do that, But should it be published anywhere? I don't think teaching for implementing of past method get accepted in any journal. @Davidmh

Answer (score 7):

A publication will get you more than such a tutorial. It is unlikely that the video or the tutorial will be cited. I don't think it will help you in formal competitions. However, much competition is informal. Say you make your videos/manual and they are used. Next time you go to a conference you'll notice that will come to you just to see what Electricman looks like in real life. You'll be noticed and that can snowball. However, you need to make a trade-off. This is a rather "soft" benefit and there is no guarantee that it will happen.

My experience along these lines is the following: I have shared a lot of tips on another statistical package because I liked doing that (some people have weird hobbies). Only later I noticed that it also benefited me (the last two jobs I received were definitely helped by my presence in this community). So if you like making videos and explaining things and you would do this as a hobby, then by all means go ahead and use the idea that it might also benefit you later on as an excuse to spend a bit more time on it (but not too much!!!).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be cited, put a number on your work!

Unless your work has an ISBN, ISSN, or DOI, you are making other people's lives difficult - both of the people citing you, and of the people trying to find your work. Finding your work can easily become tricky. There is also the risk of finding another work, since the form of a work which was uploaded can change. And people who want to check for the cited work could be confronted with a completely not related work.

Since the copyright of the videos is yours, you can still upload them. However, do that only after assigning it an ISBN number and registering it.

Citing youtube, twitter, or facebook is a no-no, unless your scientific work implies analyzing youtube, twitter, or facebook.

Publishing such educational material is less valuable than original peer-reviewed research, but at first glance people will see your work as valuable still.

Comment: I have never found it remotely "difficult" to cite something that has no "number."

Comment: I have never found using Google "difficult" or "tricky".

Comment: _Citing youtube, twitter, or facebook is a no-no_ — [citation needed]

Comment: _educational material is less valuable than original peer-reviewed research_ — [citation needed]!!

Comment: @JeffE: if you have the link, but the material changes, or disappears, it's not tricky, but impossible. The internet is volatile. Materials on it are (normally) not being gathered by national libraries. Can you assure anyone this post will be available in 1, 2 or 3 years? Isn't it obvious that youtube, twitter, or facebook do not count as a reliable source? (unless excluding the situation mentioned by me above). http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/51360/how-much-does-video-broadcasting-on-youtube-benefit-you-academic-life/51371#51371 But I cannot guarantee that his answer won't change.

Comment: @PierreB If you don't have the link, then you can't cite it anyway.  You cannot guarantee that a document with an ISBN will be available in 1–3 years, either. Publications go out of print; publishers go out of business; libraries face budget cuts.  No, it is **not** obvious that youtube, facebook, twitter don't count as reliable sources. If an idea/proof/definition/technique first appears on twitter, then you **must** cite twitter!  (At least one of my StackExchange posts has more citations than at least one of my journal papers.)

Comment: @JeffE: you seem to be completely ignorant about the existence of national libraries or interlibrary loans, if you believe that something with an ISBN can simply disappear. Equally the scientific publishing system seems like a distant planet to you.

Comment: @PierreB  With respect, I have _decades_ of direct personal experience with the scientific publishing system, as an author, referee, editor, conference chair, and arXiv moderator.  An ISBN (or ISSN, or DOI) is merely an official record that something once existed; it is **not** a guarantee of continued existence or accessibility.  National libraries do _not_ archive everything with an ISBN; books go out of print; publishers go out of business.  I have seen interlibrary loan requests for out-of-print books _with ISBNs_ fail.  If permanence were necessary, nothing would be citable.